# Flutter radio button text with icon

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

I am a Flutter beginner. We use the Dart language. How do I create a single radio button with only one country flag and country name? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
Row(
            children: [
              Text('Country & Currency',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Color(0xff8712bc),
                      decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
            ],
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text("Bahrain"),
            value: "Bahrain",
            groupValue: "bahrain",
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
```

Comment: can you include sample image and snippet that you've tried so far

Comment: Row(
            children: [
              Text('Country & Currency',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Color(0xff8712bc),
                      decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
            ],
          ),
          RadioListTile(
            title: Text("Bahrain"),
            value: "Bahrain",
            groupValue: "bahrain",
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {});
            },
          )

Comment: can you include some prototype/image of this widget structure ?

Comment: I have edited my question above. Can you please look into this? Thank you for your response!

Comment: try my post on answer, using Row on title will workout, But based on `Country & Currency',` you may find some package on pub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Row` widget on `title`.

```dart
RadioListTile(
  title: Row(
    children: [
      ///use your image
      Icon(Icons.flag),
      Text("Bahrain"),
    ],
  ),
  value: "Bahrain",
  groupValue: "bahrain",
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

Comment: Thank you! How to change the background and text color?

Comment: you need to use [TextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html). I think you can check [ui/widgets/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/layout)